# Importing xml file to pdf (Acrobat)

Tags: javascript, xml, acrobat

Is it possible (and how) to import a xml file to a fillable pdf without using Lifecycle.....just script in Acrobat Pro XI or DC?

This is for a website that loads the pdf in the browser.  I want it to populate the pdf fields with data in a xml file stored in the dame directory as the pdf.

I am fairly competent with basic javascript and acrobat...still learning and trying to avoid Ligecycle unless it is an absolute necessity for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full control over the data file(s), you could transform them into XFDF (that's the XML representation of FDF, the PDF-native form data format). Both FDF and XFDF can have a reference to their Base PDF.

With that, you would not open the PDF and then attempt to import the data, but you would open the (X)FDF, and let the Acrobat plug-in of the browser retrieve the Base PDF and do the fill-in.

If, however, you have to serve more or less any device and webbrowser, you would have to prefill the form server-side, as many PDF viewers, particularly the ones provided by the web browsers, are too dumb to deal with (X)FDF.

For server-side filling, you can either use one of the libraries floating around (iText, pdflib, etc.) or an already implemented server-side fill-in application (such as FDFMerge by Appligent).